# Does block in ansible support conditionals inside them

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm wondering if ansible supports the following scenario:

- block has a conditional with when.
- tasks inside the block has further conditionals (when) again.

Here is my current `main.yml` to illustrate:

```yaml
- block:
        
    - name: task 1  
      shell: check_install
      when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
        
    - name: task 2
      shell: echo "test task"
      when: out.rc > "0" #assuming **out** is registered above
        
  become: true
  when: sw_install|default(False) == True
```

As per ansible docs,

> Most of what you can apply to a single task (with the exception of
> loops) can be applied at the block level, which also makes it much
> easier to set data or directives common to the tasks. This does not
> mean the directive affects the block itself, but is inherited by the
> tasks enclosed by a block. i.e. a when will be applied to the tasks,
> not the block itself.

So the basic question is: if I run a playbook with the above task, how is the conditional flow iterpreted ? Does it run like an `and` condition ?

Something like:

```
run task 1  when: block conditional & task one conditional satisfies 

run task 2  when: block conditional & task two conditional satisfies
```

Comment: What's preventing you from testing it?

Comment: +1 on @VladimirBotka's question... also you're asking a question about the usage that's in the same form as the first example in the ansible block documentation.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I already did & just need to confirm if my understanding is correct

Comment: @RobH no, that's incorrect none of the example in the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) have conditional for task. Only block level conditional is set. the clarity i need is both conditionals are evaluated like an and operator.

Comment: @user2700022: Next time share the results with us and make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Zeitounator did it for you.

Comment: @VladimirBotka will make sure,  thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding a condition to a block is exactly the same as adding the same condition to each task inside the block.

If you have a condition at block level and an other at task level they will all be evaluated at task runtime.

This also means that if one of your task changes the block condition during the run, it will be re-evaluated each time. Take the following example:

```yaml
- name: Set a block condition true
  set_fact:
    block_condition: true

- name: Set a task condition true
  set_fact:
    task_condition: true

- block:
    - name: Write a message
      debug:
        msg: Block and task conditions are true
      when: task_condition | bool
    
    - name: Change condition
      set_fact:
        block_condition: false

    - name: Write a message
      debug:
        msg: Block condition is true
  
  when: block_condition | bool
```

In such a case, the last task of the block will be skipped as `block_condition` will evalutate to `false` at runtime.