# Question about "scope" of a "when" in a "block" in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to modify an existing playbook that looks like:

```yaml
---
## Capture currently installed mysql version
- name: Capture currently installed mysql version
  shell: mysql -V
  register: current_mysql_version
  ignore_errors: yes

- block:
  ## Stop running mysql instance
  - name: Stop running mysql instance
    service:
      name: mysqld
      state: stopped
      enabled: no
    ignore_errors: yes

  ## Create mysql stage directory
  - name: Create mysql stage directory
    file:
      path: "{{ play_mysql_dest_dir }}"
      state: directory
      group: root
      owner: root
      mode: 0755
.
.
.

  ## Delete mysql staging directory
  - name: Delete mysql staging directory
    file:
      path: "{{ play_mysql_dest_dir }}"
      state: absent

  ## Start mysql
  - name: Start mysql, if not started
    service:
      name: mysqld
      state: started

  ## Start tomcat
  - name: Start tomcat, if not started
    service:
      name: tomcat
      state: started
  when: current_mysql_version.stderr is search('command not found') or not play_latest_mysql_version in current_mysql_version.stdout
```

I was wondering, to WHICH tasks does the "when" get applied to?

Also, if I want to eliminate that last task (the "Start tomcat, if not started" one), do I just move the "when" line to the end of the "Start mysql, if not started" task (just for this question I am commenting out those lines, to make the change more visible), e.g.:

```yaml
---
## Capture currently installed mysql version
- name: Capture currently installed mysql version
  shell: mysql -V
  register: current_mysql_version
  ignore_errors: yes

- block:
  ## Stop running mysql instance
  - name: Stop running mysql instance
    service:
      name: mysqld
      state: stopped
      enabled: no
    ignore_errors: yes

  ## Create mysql stage directory
  - name: Create mysql stage directory
    file:
      path: "{{ play_mysql_dest_dir }}"
      state: directory
      group: root
      owner: root
      mode: 0755
.
.
.

  ## Delete mysql staging directory
  - name: Delete mysql staging directory
    file:
      path: "{{ play_mysql_dest_dir }}"
      state: absent

  ## Start mysql
  - name: Start mysql, if not started
    service:
      name: mysqld
      state: started
  when: current_mysql_version.stderr is search('command not found') or not play_latest_mysql_version in current_mysql_version.stdout

  ## Start tomcat
#      - name: Start tomcat, if not started
#        service:
#          name: tomcat
#          state: started
#      when: current_mysql_version.stderr is search('command not found') or not play_latest_mysql_version in current_mysql_version.stdout
```

I think that the intention of the original developer was that the "when" should apply to each/all of the tasks starting from the "-block", but I am wondering if the "indentation" of the "when" line is correct (or not)?  I am fairly new to working with Ansible :(...

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: The `when` which applies to the block should be at the exact same level as the `block` statement (i.e it is an other key in the same dictionnary level). When it is there, it applies to all task in the block in the exact same way as if you added that when to each task. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394267/does-block-in-ansible-support-conditionals-inside-them/57394565#57394565) can help.

Comment: [Does block in Ansible support conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394267/does-block-in-ansible-support-conditionals-inside-them) or [Playbook blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) answer your question?